# Array bound mismatch error using rank 2+ array as derived type component

Tags: arrays, fortran

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564872/using-assumed-rank-fortran-array-as-derived-type-component), I'm trying to create a derived type `Result2D` that has a rank-2 array `data` as a property, that is filled with data by a procedure `init()`:

```
type, public :: Result2D
    class(*), allocatable :: data(:,:)

    contains
        procedure, public :: init
end type

contains
    subroutine init(this, data)
        class(Result2D) :: this,
        class(*) :: data(:,:)

        allocate(this%data, source=data)
    end subroutine
```

However, calling init with a rank-2 array results in an array bound mismatch error in GFortran, on the line with the `allocate` statement: `Array bound mismatch for dimension 1 of array '<<unknown>>' (4/2)`. I don't understand why this would be happening, and it works fine for rank-1 arrays (but not for anything rank-2 and above).

An example of the code calling `init()`:

```
type(Result2D) :: r
integer :: i(2,2)

i(1,:) = [1,2]
i(2,:) = [3,4]
call r%init(i)
```

Comment: Can you see whether it's related [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34384145/)?  That is, try putting explicit bounds into the allocation statement.

Comment: It appears to be related, putting explicit bounds in the allocate statement gets rid of the error: `allocate(this%data(size(data,1),size(data,2)), source=data(size(data,1),size(data,2)))`. Thanks!

Comment: I was a bit premature there, using the `allocate()` statement I wrote in the previous statement just allocates the final element of `data` to all of the `this%data` array. Specifying the bounds like `this%data(1:size(data,1),1:size(data,2))` still results in the same error.

Comment: Specifying `-fcheck=no-bounds` removes the error and the program works as expected, so unless I'm mistaken this seems like a GFortran bug?

Comment: It might be. Do you use any optimizations? Try `-O1`.

Comment: Already using -O1.

Comment: Agreed that it's potentially a compiler problem.